# $filter with nested $cond

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with following two concerned fields in it.

```
{
      currentStage: ObjectId("5b06999d889de3bd613ab79d"),
      stagePermissions: [
           {
            "stage" : ObjectId("5b06999d889de3bd613ab79d"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b3ca6ed676af0e70150a7b9"),
            "permissions" : [ 
                "admin"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "stage" : ObjectId("587d33db87969c1b380fb903"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b3ca6ed676af0e70150a7b8"),
            "permissions" : [ 
                "admin"
            ]
        }, 
      ]
}
```

What I need to query is get documents having their current stage permissions to "admin".

So what I need is match `"stagePermissions.permissions": "admin"`. But the problem is stagePermissions has permissions for all stages. I only need to match `currentStage` with `stagePermissions.permissions`.

In other words what I want to do is following because I don't have currentStage's id as filter I only have "admin" to filter against.

`"stagePermissions.stage": "document's currentStage" AND "stagePermissions": "admin"`

Expected Output:

All documents having their `currentStage` permissions set to "admin" in `stagePermissions`.

Comment: what should be the output from above collection?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have just updated my question.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I need all "stagePermissions" not just the one matching also I don't have currentStage Id to filter, I need to access it from the current document being processed.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Bascially I'm trying to get those documents which has "admin" as permissions to their currentStage. and all stagePermissions are being stored the same document as well.

Comment: Both. `stagePermissions.stage === currentStage and stagePermissions.permissions === 'admin'`

Comment: No my friend as I said I don't have currentStage id to filter against. I need all documents having "admin" in their currentStage's permissions from "stagePermissions.permissions" array.

Comment: Not just the one matching with `ObjectId("5b06999d889de3bd613ab79d")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build query for relating parent document's field to embedded array document's field. Using MongoDB aggregation Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054665/how-to-build-query-for-relating-parent-documents-field-to-embedded-array-docume)

Comment: This is identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097633/2071807) which has a nice, concise answer using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "stagePermissions": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$stagePermissions",
          "as": "stagePermission",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$stagePermission.stage",
                  "$currentStage"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$in": [
                  "admin",
                  "$$stagePermission.permissions"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "currentStage": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "stagePermissions": {
        "$ne": []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kafophEHAov)

Comment: @LondonRob If we make good architecture for schema then mongodb is precisely  the best database... But newbies cannot do that and go for nested fields... And also now join is easily possible with mongodb so it is good to go with mongodb now

Comment: @LondonRob Actually I'm working on an existing project and yeah its designed in mongodb but with all styles like SQL based db schema.